# Using dispatch_once or static vars in a lazy var

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

From the [Swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID255):

> If a property marked with the lazy modifier is accessed by multiple threads simultaneously and the property has not yet been initialized, there is no guarantee that the property will be initialized only once.

So, from that I understand that using

```
class SomeClass {
    lazy var someVar: SomeOtherClass = {
       return SomeOtherClass()
    }()
}
```

is not a thread-safe way to ensure everyone that uses the SomeClass instance, uses the same `SomeOtherClass` instance as `SomeClass().someVar`.

If that's the case, is using

```
class SomeClass {
    lazy var someVarr: SomeOtherClass = {
        var some: SomeOtherClass? = nil
        var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        dispatch_once(&token) {
            some = SomeOtherClass()
        }
        return some!
    }()
}
```

or using:

```
class SomeClass {
    lazy var someVarrr: SomeOtherClass = {
        struct Static {
            static let some = SomeOtherClass()
        }
        return Static.some
    }()
}
```

the right, thread-safe way to instantiate SomeOtherClass?

To provide some context: In Objective-C, I used:

```
-(NSURLSession *)ephemeralURLSession {
    if (!_ephemeralURLSession) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
            _ephemeralURLSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
        });
    }
    return _ephemeralURLSession;
}
```

and now I wonder what the right way is to instantiate `NSURLSession` in Swift, for example:

```
lazy var ephemeralURLSession: NSURLSession = {
    var session: NSURLSession? = nil
    var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    dispatch_once(&token) {
        let configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
        session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
    }
    return session!
}()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define it like this:

```
static let ephemeralURLSession: NSURLSession = {
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
    return NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
}()
```

This is both lazy and thread safe.

Comment: And if I would want a new `ephemeralURLSession` for each instance of the class?

Comment: This piece of code doesn't let you do that, since it declares a `type property`, which is shared among all instances of the object. If that's what you need checking out [page 75 of this book](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=opwzBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=dispatch_once+lazy+var+swift&source=bl&ots=h7O68Iug8a&sig=XqO9TjAvIk_-I8w1ATJ8dtf3XYc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKy5yO1K7LAhVCliwKHWZJB-gQ6AEISjAH#v=onepage&q=dispatch_once%20lazy%20var%20swift&f=false) might be helpful.

Comment: That's quite a bit of code. I hope there is something more concise. But thanks for the link & answer.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope you can find something prettier too but it looks like  you are better off using a constant NSURLSession that you initialize in your class' init function if it isn't a must to use a lazy var.